# Updating observable values in ObservableArray knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observableArray and an observable as below.

```
self.unreadcount = ko.observable();

self.searchFilters = ko.observableArray([
    {label: "A", active: ko.observable(false), count1: self.unreadcount()},
    {label: "B", active: ko.observable(false), count1: self.unreadcount()},
    {label: "C", active: ko.observable(false), count1: self.unreadcount()}
]);
```

In one particular function , I have passed some value to self.unreadcount(),
 I need to update my observableArray also accordingly.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `count1` property with the `self.unreadcount` observable.

```
self.searchFilters = ko.observableArray([
    {label: "A", active: ko.observable(false), count1: self.unreadcount},
    {label: "B", active: ko.observable(false), count1: self.unreadcount},
    {label: "C", active: ko.observable(false), count1: self.unreadcount}
]);
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qfaTj/)

Or can bind the `count1` property to the `$parent.unreadcount` :

```
<div data-bind="foreach : searchFilters">
    <span data-bind="text : label"></span> 
    <span data-bind="text : $parent.unreadcount"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

JS

```
var VM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.unreadcount = ko.observable();

   self.searchFilters = ko.observableArray([
    {label: "A", active: ko.observable(false)},
    {label: "B", active: ko.observable(false)},
    {label: "C", active: ko.observable(false)}
   ]);
};
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qfaTj/1/)

And if you need to update `count1` manually; you can do that :

```
self.searchFilters = ko.observableArray([
    {label: "A", active: ko.observable(false), count1: ko.observable(self.unreadcount())},
    {label: "B", active: ko.observable(false), count1: ko.observable(self.unreadcount())},
    {label: "C", active: ko.observable(false), count1: ko.observable(self.unreadcount())}
]);

self.update = function(newValue) {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach( self.searchFilters(), function(row) {
        row.count1(newValue);
    });
}
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qfaTj/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are after, but I've created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RFc3r/2/, which uses your `observableArray` and allows you to update the counts per row.

Markup:

```
<p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(searchFilters)"></p>
<div class="liveExample" data-bind="foreach: searchFilters"> 
   <p>Label:<input data-bind="value: label"></input></p>
   <p>Active:<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: active"></input></p>
   <p>Unread:<input data-bind="value: count1"></input></p>
   <input type="button" data-bind="click: changeValue(count1)" value="click me"/>
   <hr/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    self.unreadcount = ko.observable(0);

    self.searchFilters = ko.observableArray([{
        label: "A",
        active: ko.observable(false),
        count1: ko.observable(self.unreadcount())
    }, {
        label: "B",
        active: ko.observable(true),
        count1: ko.observable(self.unreadcount())
    }, {
        label: "C",
        active: ko.observable(false),
        count1: ko.observable(self.unreadcount())
    }]);

    self.changeValue = function(item){
       item(item() + 1); 
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```